# MIT SCRATCH BUILD How to create custom blocks or change text

Tags: mit-scratch

I Cloned the repository [Scratch-GUI](https://github.com/LLK/scratch-gui)
I did `npm install` & `npm start`
Works perfectly in http://localhost:8601/ ,

now,

- I have to `change the text&color` of the `pre-built block` *without* changing the result(change the color of one `=` block and change its text from `=` to `equal`)
- I want to create/add a `new block`

How to do it (where to change/add)

*( I have only setuped scratch-GUI ,I didn't setup scratch VM/scratchblocks because without that itself the localhost is working )*

Answer (score 1):

`scratch-blocks`, `scratch-vm`, etc. are already installed when you install `scratch-gui`. First you need to write the code to be ran when the block is clicked. Define that in `node-modules/scratch-vm/src/blocks/scratch3_[the category you want].js`. Next you need to define the block in `scratch-blocks`. To  do that navigate to `node-modules/scratch-blocks/blocks-vertical/[the category you want].js`. And finally you need to add your block to the toolbox. It's in `node-modules/scratch-blocks/blocks_vertical/default_toolbox.js`.